# Forward a POST request with additional params

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, forward

Is there a way to forward a POST request from one controller to another with additional param(s)?

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form action"${contextPath}/controller1/post">
  <input name="field1" type="text"/>
  <input name="field2" type="text"/>
  <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This form will post to controller1.post() method.

But now I have another controller - `controller2` also with a `post` method.
I now want to post to `controller2.post` so I could add some parameters to the request before forwarding to `controller1`.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: All controllers are just classes on a server side..Therefore, if you need to change something you can still call controller1 and inside call controller2. After you get a result from the controller2 and add what you want.Point is if you call controller2 when in your browser you will see its address.So you can again call controller1 from controller2 and use the controller2 result.Choose either way based on what url you wanna show in the browser.

Comment: I know that controllers are just classes and I can call one controller's method from another as long as the method is public. 
What I don't know is how to add a param to the set of params in a request.

Answer (score 6):

You can try that if this is what you are looking for

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller1/{id}", method = RequestMethod.Post)
public void doSomething(
        @PathVariable Long id, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

     request.setAttribute("id",Id);

     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("your url/controller2");
     rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

And after in controller2

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller2", method = RequestMethod.Post)
public string doSomething2(Model model,       
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

     model.addAttribute("id", request.getAttribute("id"));

    return "myView";
}
```

Comment: no. This is not exactly what I'm looking for. 
I need to modify the request directly and add a param to the request, just like the param is from the form.